# Probability about cards

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

Eight hands of five cards each are dealt from a shuffled deck of cards without replacement so that there are twelve undealt cards. Find the probability that at least one of these hands has no diamonds.

The solution uses the inclusion-exclusion theorem. Is there any other way to solve this problem without using that theorem?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mathsexplorer The complement is that all hands have at least one diamond.

Comment: oops sorry I didn't read it properly

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by computing the probability that each hand has at least one diamond, and subtracting from $1$.  While this doesn't use inclusion-exclusion, I don't think it's easier, and I do think it's more error- prone.

You'd have to start by figuring out the ways that the $13$ Diamonds can be distributed.  We have $9$ numbers that add up to $13$, that is is we add up the number of Diamonds in each hand, and the number remaining in the undealt portion of the deck.  The numbers in the hands must be positive, but the number in the deck can be zero.  That is, we must consider the [$5$ partitions of $13$ into $9$ parts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partitions+of+13+into+9+parts), and the [$7$ partitions of $13$ into $5$ parts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partitions+of+13+into+8+parts).  Also, we must take cognizance that a partition like $5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$ corresponds to $2$ cases: one where each hand is dealt $1$ Diamond, and one where $7$ hands are dealt $1$ Diamond and the fifth is dealt $5$.  The partition $4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$ corresponds to $3$ different cases.

I think you'll agree that inclusion-exclusion is a superior method.

This assumes that you want the theoretical exact answer.  Simulation is a practical alternative.  Personally, if I did it by inclusion-exclusion, I would check my answer by simulation.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** A simulation of a million iterations
of this game approximates the answer as
$0.9248\pm 0.0005.$

In the R code below, in `deck` Diamonds are `1`s, cards of
other suites are `0`; `dlt` is a 40-vector of cards dealt; `h1` is $0$ if there are no Diamonds in Hand 1, and so on for the other seven hands. Thus. `nd`
has a million elements: $0$ if one or more hands
has no Diamond. Finally, `mean(nd)` is the proportion of iterations in which one or more hands had no Diamond. With a million iterations we can
expect simulation error of $\pm 0.001.$

```
deck = c(rep(1,13),rep(0,39))
set.seed(2020)
m = 10^6;  nd = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 dlt = sample(deck, 40)
 h1 = sum(dlt[1:5]);    h2 = sum(dlt[6:10])
 h3 = sum(dlt[11:15]);  h4 = sum(dlt[16:20])
 h5 = sum(dlt[21:25]);  h6 = sum(dlt[26:30])
 h7 = sum(dlt[31:35]);  h8 = sum(dlt[36:40])
 nd[i] = h1*h2*h3*h4*h5*h6*h7*h8 }
mean(nd==0)
[1] 0.924804
2*sd(nd==0)/1000
0.0005274149    # aprx 95% margin of sim error
```

*Note:* Consider the following *very rough* combinatorial approximation. The probability that
*one* 5-card hand avoids Diamonds is
${{13\choose 0}{39\choose 5}}/{{52\choose 5}} \approx 0.22.$ Then, *if the eight hands were independent,* the probability of at least one hand
without Diamonds would be about $1 - .78^8 \approx 0.86.$

Comment: I think one of us has made an error.  Using inclusion-exclusion, I got $0.9246758210484046$.  Simulation of a million deals gave $0.924708$, so I feel pretty confident.  I don't know R, but the first line looks suspect to me.  Should the last expression be $rep(0,3\color{red}9)$?

Comment: @sualuspatz. Thanks much for spotting my typo. Need to get new glasses, I think. Will fix my simulation. // Also, thanks for your nice answer (+1).